# Select query to get total records count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table with status column. How to get total number of records, total number of records with pass status and total number of records with fail status using SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a query similar to

```
select 
Count(*) as TotalRecords, 
Sum(case where status = 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as PassRecords,
Sum(case where status = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as FaileRecords
from Table
```

Comment: I'm assuming there could be other values in status that we don't care about

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Status WITH ROLLUP
```

This will work if those two statuses (pass, fail) are the only statuses (otherwise you'll need a `WHERE Status IN ('fail', 'pass')` condition additionally) - and the `WITH ROLLUP` will also give you the total number of rows for all statuses (with a `Status = NULL` in the output)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with case statements and aggregations:

```
select count(*), sum(case when status = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) as pass,
       sum(case when status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) as fail
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other alternatives (SQL Server 2008+):

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE([status] CHAR(4));

INSERT @foo SELECT 'pass'
UNION ALL SELECT 'pass'
UNION ALL SELECT 'fail';

-- option #1:

SELECT [status], c = COUNT(*)
FROM @foo
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(([status]), ());

-- option #2:

SELECT [status], c = COUNT(*)
FROM @foo
GROUP BY [status]
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, COUNT(*) OVER() FROM @foo;
```